# Recursively scrape website using scrapy

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I need to recursively crawl through a website. This is what I have right now:

```
class DemoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'sample_recursive'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.org']
    start_urls = [
        "http://example.org"
    ]

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'/.org/site/ID/[\w*\W*]*'), deny=(r'.org/subscription')), callback='parse_start_url', follow=True)]
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        items = []
        item = DemoSampleItem()
        item["source_url"] = response.url
        item["title"] = response.xpath('//div[@class="content-title"]/h2/text()')[0].extract()
        item["breadcrumb"] = response.xpath("//ul[@class='breadcrumbs']")[0].extract()
        item["content"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='main_col']")[0].extract()
        item["right_col"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='right_col']").extract()
        item["left_col"] = response.xpath("//div[@class='left_col']")[0].extract()
        item["depth"] = response.meta.get('depth', 0)
        items.append(item)

        return items
```

I want it to scrape through pages like: "example.org", "example.org/site/ID/home", "example.org/site/ID/Partners" and "example.org/site/ID/home/our-values" 
and then save each item pipeline into the mysql db as an entry of its own.

```
class AcdiSamplePipeline(object):

    # connect
    db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='user', passwd='passwd', db='dbname'
                                    , charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)

    # create a database cursor
    cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        source_url = item["source_url"]
        title = item["title"].encode('utf-8')
        breadcrumb = item["breadcrumb"].encode('utf-8')
        content = item["content"].encode('utf-8')
        left_col = item["left_col"].encode('utf-8')
        right_col = item["right_col"].encode('utf-8')
        depth = item["depth"]

        try:
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table_name (source_url, title, breadcrumb, content
                                , right_col, left_col, page_depth)
                                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
                                (source_url
                                 , title
                                 , breadcrumb
                                 , content
                                 , right_col
                                 , left_col
                                 , depth))

            self.db_connection.commit()

        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print("--------------- Printing DB ERROR(s) -------------------")
            print "ERROR WHILE DB WRITE %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])

        return item
```

But as of now its only scraping and saving "example.org" in database. Any idea why it wouldn't recursively go through the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression in your LinkExtractor looks wrong:

```
allow=(r'/.org/site/ID/[\w*\W*]*')
      #   ^--- this slash doesn't belong here.
      #   Plus, the dot should be escaped, else it matches any character
```

It seems you want regex more like:

```
allow=(r'[.]org/site/ID/.+')
```